# Sles11sp3 sdk iso repository local or online

Tags: sdk, iso, suse, sles

I need SDK iso for sles 11 sp3, or way to bypass that without mounting, I need some rpms that are included to that dvd, i.e `libqt4-devel` which need more devel dependencies. Any idea where I can find it for download or way to bypass it ?
(official website and novell website doesn't host it anymore.)

Thanks